# Symfony 2.8 form forces absent boolean values to false

Tags: json, forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm very new to Symfony and have having issues implementing a RESTful API, in particular a form for which the incoming JSON doesn't include all the parameters.

So far I setup a controller handling a POST request. The application POSTs a JSON containing either an `isPaired` and/or an `isTutorialSeen` fields.

- Case 1 (working case):

When the POST query contains `{"isTutorialSeen":true, "isPaired": true}`, then both fields are set to true when I try `$form->get('isPaired')->getData()` or `$form->get('isTutorialSeen')->getData()`. This is what I expect.

- Case 2 (not working case):

When the POST query contains `{"isTutorialSeen":true}`, then I can see that the isPaired field of the form is set to false when I try `$form->get('isPaired')->getData()`. Probably because the field was not passed in the JSON. Not passing it in the JSON should have the meaning "don't update it", and not "set it to false". Same than HTTP 'PATCH' grammar.

I'm scratching my hair trying to figure out how I could get a 'null' for example instead of a 'false' return here.

My controller is implemented as follows :

```
/**
     * @Rest\Post("/installation/state")
     *
*/
public function installationStateAction(Request $request, Subscription $subscription)
{
    $view = null;

    $form = $this->createForm(InstallationStateType::class);
    ControllerUtils::handleForm($request, $form);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $isPaired    = $form->get('isPaired')->getData();
        $isTutorialSeen = $form->get('isTutorialSeen')->getData();

        if ($isPaired !== null)
            $subscription->setIsPaired($isPaired);

        if ($isTutorialSeen !== null)
            $subscription->setIsTutorialSeen($isTutorialSeen);

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush($subscription);
    }

     $view = $this->view($subscription, Codes::HTTP_OK);
     return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

The InstallationStateType is as follows:

```
/**
 * Form for InstallationState.
 */
class InstallationStateType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('isTutorialSeen', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false]);
        $builder->add('isPaired', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false]);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $defaultsOptions = [
            'data_class' => null
        ];

        $resolver->setDefaults($defaultsOptions);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'installationstate';
    }
}
```

The Subscription entity fields are :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_paired", options={"default"=FALSE})
 *
 * @JSON\Expose
 * @JSON\Groups({"api_process"})
 * @JSON\Since("1.0")
 * @JSON\SerializedName("isPaired")
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
protected $isPaired;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_tutorial_seen", options={"default"=FALSE})
 *
 * @JSON\Expose
 * @JSON\Groups({"api_process"})
 * @JSON\Since("1.0")
 * @JSON\SerializedName("isTutorialSeen")
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
protected $isTutorialSeen;
```

Maybe the options={"default"=FALSE} in the entity configuration is responsible for this, but although it makes sense in the persistence layer to have false as a default value, having it forced to false in the layer responsible of mapping form data (or absent data) to object is not what I need.
Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: In Case 2, are you doing an update of your entity?

Comment: @MatkoĐipalo Yes, in case 2, I update the entity iff the fields are not null. As you can seen, the fields are always non-null, even though they are not provided in the request.

Answer (score -1):

Default field value for entity is set like this:

```
protected $isTutorialSeen = null;
```

but I am not sure if it will help in that case.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

When you are going to create a totally new resource, you use POST method. By design, the POST request method requests that a web server accepts and store the data enclosed in the body of the request message.

If you've decided to update your resource, you should create PUT or PATCH request. PATCH is mostly just like PUT, except you don't need to send up the entire resource body.

So, the first thing you have to change is - use PUT (or PATCH) for updating.

If you are going to use PUT you must send an entire representation of the resource. If you don't send isPaired, the server should nullify it - in your case, the server will set it to the default value.

If you are going to use PATCH, you can omit isPaierd, and it won't be changed, but you must find code that submits a form and add the second parameter with value true.

```
$form->submit($data, true);
```

Symfony\Component\Form|FormInterface:

```
/**
 * Submits data to the form, transforms and validates it.
 *
 * @param null|string|array $submittedData The submitted data
 * @param bool              $clearMissing  Whether to set fields to NULL
 *                                         when they are missing in the
 *                                         submitted data.
 *
 * @return FormInterface The form instance
 *
 * @throws Exception\AlreadySubmittedException If the form has already been submitted.
 */
public function submit($submittedData, $clearMissing = true);
```

Comment: Changing the verb from POST to PATCH is not possible, so I tried using PUT. I replaced ControllerUtils::handleForm($request, $form) by a $form->submit($request->request->all(),true). The behaviour didn't change. The $form->get('isPaired')->getData() returned value is still false, like if it as not nullified.